# How to implement post ranking algorithm in rails with only upvotes?

Tags: ruby, algorithm, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a post model and want to display the post according to their popularity. I want to implement this with only upvote and the time difference.

I have looked at the reddit comment ranking algorithm but it uses both upvotes and downvotes.

Comment: What exactly is your question? What exactly have you tried? Why are you not happy with your current solution?

Comment: I tried to implement the post ranking algorithm with only two parameters (Time difference and the upvotes) but I don't know how to go with this

Comment: What is wrong for you with just using the same algorithm and set downvotes to zero? Can you explain, using code and a short example, what you are looking for?

Comment: Will this effect the accuracy of the ranking or not?

Comment: The ranking is never "accurate" to any real world measurement, so that is not a question that can be answered. It just has an effect that some people find useful. The result should be identical to that of a reddit comment list where no-one has downvoted.

Comment: thanks for the advise

Comment: One more thing:- Calculating the popularity rank on runtime vs storing the popularity in database. Which one is more effective?

Comment: How do you propose the stored popularity to reflect elapsed time?

Comment: I just want to use the popularity to display the posts according to their popularity